# DELETE query is still runing and have critical problems

Tags: mysql

HI Last night i use this query

```
DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE  last_change < 1332201600 && last_change !=0
```

but frist problem is after this mysql make my last_change field =0
and the second problem is after 8 hours the table of message get more and get lower for example go to 1,000,000 and then go to 2,000,000 then go 1,500,000 ............
what is the problem?

Comment: What is the data type of last_change? Is the column indexed?

Comment: Use `timestamp()` function. See my answer @babakfaghihian

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the `timestamp` value in integer, try this query, as there is no operator like `&&` and not advisable to use `!=`:

```
DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE  `last_change` < TIMESTAMP('1332201600') AND NOT `last_change` 0;
```

Coz, an example to show about this query is:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2003-12-31 12:00:00','12:00:00');
    -> '2004-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: what shoud i do know query is still running

Comment: Did you try this? Adding a `TIMESTAMP()` function? And also replacing `&&` with `AND` and `!=` with `NOT`?

Comment: delete query is runing but now show in process list i scare to do a new query

Comment: Take a backup of dump of data, and then try once again, what if it works?

Comment: my bro plz help me its big site how can i chat with u ?plzplzplz

Comment: the problem is that database now is 1,000,000 2seconds later is 1,500,000 what is the problem if it delete how it can grow????????